# Как правильно создать или обновить пользователя при регистрации

Tags: laravel, валидация, laravel5

В БД существует таблица, в таблице есть два поля:
**phone** - *должен быть уникальным*
**status** (активирован аккаунт или нет)

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'phone' => 'required|phone:AUTO,RU|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
])
$validator->validate();
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));
```

С созданием пользователя проблем нет, но если пользователь не закончил регистрацию (в прошлый раз) как обойти валидацию и правильно составить условие?

Comment: что значит "не закончил?"

Comment: не подтвердил номер телефона (отправляю код по смс)

Comment: на данный момент сделал так: 
убрал из валидации "unique:users" и сделал свою проверку User::where('phone', $request->phone)->count() === 0
а дальше уже условия разные